# Arboles binarios recursión java

Tags: java, eclipse, recursión

Resulta que tengo que armar un método llamado "numerosPares" en una clase llamada "contadorArbol" el cual inserte en una Lista genérica enlazada, aquellos datos del árbol binario (recibido en el constructor de la clase) que sean divisibles por 2 y que devuelva la estructura (la lista genérica enlazada) .

Mi duda es el método "numerosPares". 
     Esta es mi solución no se si será
     correcta. (La instancia de la lista genérica enlazada tomenla como que ya está 
  declarada, con una variable de instancia "l")

```
public listaGenericaEnlazada<t>numerosPares(){


 if(a.getDatoRaiz().esVacio()) {
        return null;
 }else {
        if(a.getDatoRaiz%2==0) {
            l.agregarFinal(getDatoRaiz());
        }
        getHijoIzquierdo().numerosPares();
        getHijoDerecho().numerosPares();
        return l;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase arbol binario con sus metodos **getHijoDerecho()** , **getHijoIzquierdo()**  , **getDatoRaiz()** y **esVacio()** que son los que utilizo =

```
public class ArbolBinario<T> {

private NodoBinario<T> raiz;

public ArbolBinario(T dato) {
    this.raiz = new NodoBinario<T>(dato);
}

private ArbolBinario(NodoBinario<T> nodo) {
    this.raiz = nodo;
}

private NodoBinario<T> getRaiz() {
    return raiz;
}


public T getDatoRaiz() {
    if (this.getRaiz() != null) {
        return this.getRaiz().getDato(); //El dato lo tiene la nodoBinario.
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public ArbolBinario<T> getHijoIzquierdo() {
    return new ArbolBinario<T>(this.raiz.getHijoIzquierdo());
}

public ArbolBinario<T> getHijoDerecho() {
    return new ArbolBinario<T>(this.raiz.getHijoDerecho());
}

public void agregarHijoIzquierdo(ArbolBinario<T> hijo) {
    this.raiz.setHijoIzquierdo(hijo.getRaiz());
}

public void agregarHijoDerecho(ArbolBinario<T> hijo) {
    this.raiz.setHijoDerecho(hijo.getRaiz());
}

public void eliminarHijoIzquierdo() {
    this.raiz.setHijoIzquierdo(null);
}

public void eliminarHijoDerecho() {
    this.raiz.setHijoDerecho(null);
}

public boolean esVacio() {
    return this.getDatoRaiz() == null;
}

public boolean esHoja() {
    return this.getDatoRaiz() != null && this.getHijoIzquierdo().esVacio() && this.getHijoDerecho().esVacio();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la recursión con un método inOrder debería ser algo del tipo:

```
numerosPares(node.getHijoIzquierdo());
numerosPares(node.elem());
numerosPares(node.getHijoDerecho());
```

El caso base está bien.
Como parece que no tienes ninguna restricción sobre el orden esta implementación debería ser suficiente.

Este algoritmo inOrder recorre:

Hijos izquierda-Nodo central-Hijos derecha.

Comment: Hola adrian, gracias por responder. Igualmente fijate que mi metodo no recibe ningun tipo de parametro, por lo tanto no podria realizar lo que me estarias planteando.

Comment: Podrías pasar el código completo o al menos  los métodos getHijo? Estoy ahora mismo preparándome el temario de arboles binarios para examen y tal y este tipo de ejercicios me vienen genial, a ver si entre los dos lo resolvemos.

Comment: Ahi edite mi post con la clase Arbol Binario y sus metodos que necesitas saber. Sabes si se pueden enviar mensajes por privado en esta pagina? Porque tengo mas ejercicios de arboles los cuales tengo un par de dudas, pero estos son de arboles binarios de busqueda.

Comment: Lo siento, pero creo que no tengo el conocimiento suficiente como para ayudarte, no implemento métodos con tipos genéricos. Aún así viendo los métodos no me queda del todo claro si recorres todo el árbol para lo comprobación.